# Unable to find documentation on UIDeviceRGBColorSpace

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm currently learning iOS developement using Swift. I have tried to google and also have tried search Apple's offical documentation, but I was unable to find documentations on `UIDeviceRGBColorSpace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDeviceRGBColorSpace is a way to represent colors in code. You'd see it in the form of UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1, where it is followed by four numbers. The four numbers stand for red, green, blue, and alpha.

An example: Red Color = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 (all red, no blue, no green, and full alpha)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information!! I was just wondering does apple have any kind of documentation on this class? or its something they can't be bothered coming up with a documentation.....

Comment: I have just done some searching, it seems that Apple does not have any documentation on this specific item. This is most likely because you would not use this in code. The only time I have seen it is if I NSLog a color, it will return a UIDeviceRGBColorSpace with 4 values. If you were creating a UI element with RGB colors, you would use UIColor or CIColor.